# Color Change of stacked menu and social media based on background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Im trying to replicate this sites color change of the hamburger and social media based on the the background of the div https://pithworks.com/

As you scroll you can see that it changes color based on a light and darker background. I've tried several options such as colourBrightness.js and background-check.js and have no success.

Any ideas on how to get his to work.

Thanks

Comment: isnt it working ? i dont see the problem

Comment: It's not based on scrolling, the color changes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution :

```js
var cursor = 0;
var direction = -1;
var fps = 15; // frames per second

// -0.25 ... 0 ... 0.25
//           ^
//         cursor

setInterval(function () {
  cursor += direction * 0.01;
  if (Math.abs(cursor) > 0.25) direction *= -1;
  document.body.style.background = makeGradient(cursor);
}, 1000 / fps);

function makeGradient (cursor) {
  var p1 = Math.round(cursor * 100);
  var p2 = Math.round((cursor + 1) * 100);
  return "linear-gradient(45deg, "
  + "#ff2200 " + p1 + "%, "
  + "#23548b " + p2 + "%"
  + ")";
}
```

```css
html,body{padding:0;margin:0;height:100%;}
```

See http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor.